# Proof that positive elements' square summation of one sequence is compared with that of the other

Tags: inequality

There are two real sequences with $n$ elements, $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ and $y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n$. The two sequences both satisfy:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^nx_i=0,\quad\sum_{i=0}^nx_i^2=n,\quad\sum_{i=0}^ny_i=0,\quad\sum_{i=0}^ny_i^2=n.
$$
We define the function as follows
$$
\sigma(\cdot)=\left\{\begin{aligned}1,&\quad\text{the condition is True,}\\0,&\quad\text{the condition is False.}\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
If
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(x_i>0)>\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(y_i>0),
$$
please prove
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(x_i>0)x_i^2<\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(y_i>0)y_i^2.
$$

Explanation: I need to handle two sequences with the same number of elements, but I am only interested in the elements above their mean value. Therefore, I normalize the two sequences such that the resulting sequences have 0 mean value and 1 standard deviation.
Initially, I want to determine
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(x_i>0)x_i^2<\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(y_i>0)y_i^2\Rightarrow\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(x_i>0)>\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(y_i>0),
$$
but apparently, this question is not right. Therefore, I explored the inverse question
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(x_i>0)>\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(y_i>0)\Rightarrow\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(x_i>0)x_i^2<\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sigma(y_i>0)y_i^2.
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is the source of this question, please?

Comment: Majorization seems promising here. But please, add some context as per the link above.